# Different access permissions for different classes

Tags: java, oop, inner-classes

Suppose i have class University with fields "TopSecretData" and field "NbOfStudents" and I want to make two classes Staff and Course where Staff can only see TopSecretData while Course can only see NbOfStudents.

I tried to use inner classes, but it doesnt make sense as inner classes can access all fields, so any suggestions ? THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: You need a permissions system that renders different parts of the UI based on some role you assign to the user. Many frameworks have built in authorization systems, but since you haven't included any technical details about your project whatsoever, it's impossible to provide more guidance. Remember, Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum where you can shape your question over time -- your question has to make sense from the outset. Read up on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) well formed questions which will receive useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

We can define separate classes for Staff and Course, and then provide appropriate methods in the University class to allow controlled access to the fields.The University class retains control over who has access to its fields by employing these strategies. As inner classes of the University class, the Staff and Course classes are permitted to call these methods, but they are unable to directly access the private fields "topSecretData" and "nbOfStudents".

```
public class University {
    private String topSecretData;
    private int nbOfStudents;
    
    // Method to allow Staff to access TopSecretData
    public String getTopSecretData(Staff staff) { 
         return this.topSecretData;
    }
    // Method to allow Course to access NbOfStudents
    public int getNbOfStudents(Course course) {
         return this.noOfStudents;
    }
    public class Staff(){
    }
    public class Course(){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The visibility delegation you're looking for isn't a property of *Java* inheritance.

You'll need to configure the data accordingly.

*[Inheritance (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Interfaces and Inheritance)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)*.

```java
class NbOfStudents {
    int value;
}

class TopSecretData {
    String data;
}

class Staff {
    TopSecretData topSecretData;
}

class Course {
    NbOfStudents nbOfStudents;
}
```